# After updating to iOS 13 suggestion(email, phone number, first name...) for UITextField don't appear above keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

After updating device to iOS 13 input suggestion for inputField(UITextField). Like email, phone number, first name, last name don't appear above keyboard anymore. First image iOS 12.4.1 have suggested email, second image iOS 13.1.2 don't have any suggestion. Same demo app is build with xCode Version 11.0 (11A419c) on iPhone 7 iOS 12.4.1(first image, work as expected). iPhone 7 iOS 13.1.2(second image, don't have any suggestion above keyboard)
I tested by adding textContentType in storyboard and also by adding next line in code directly

```
email.textContentType = .emailAddress
```

[image: On iOS 12.4.1 everting working as expected]

and

[image: iOS 13.1.2 don't show suggestion]

Comment: Xcode version ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So for iOS 13 (or higher), I noticed that setting the following properties makes  iPhone to suggest you all the data:

**For email ensure all these three properties are set:**

```
 emailField.autocorrectionType = .yes
 emailField.textContentType = .emailAddress
 emailField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

**For first name and last name:**

```
firstNameField.autocorrectionType = .yes
firstNameField.textContentType = .givenName
firstNameField.keyboardType = .namePhonePad

lastNameField.autocorrectionType = .yes
lastNameField.textContentType = .familyName
lastNameField.keyboardType = .namePhonePad
```

**For phone number its a bit tricky:**

```
phoneField.autocorrectionType = .yes
phoneField.textContentType = .telephoneNumber
phoneField.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
```

Also make sure that **Predictive** in **Keyboards Setting** of device is **turned on**. If **it doesn't work** at once **turn it off** wait for a few seconds and then **turn on again** and boom it would be working again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: For names and phone numbers you can set "keyboardType" to ".namePhonePad"

Comment: Phone number suggestions still aren't working for me when running a debug build 

Comment: I have search many application in case of phoneField.keyboardType = .numberPad  , the Lyft Application do it in same how?

Comment: This is the easiest explanation that I found, and it actually works :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Important** note after you have configured your textField text content type with `.telephoneNumber`, you must have a phone number in your contact card.

Go to the contacts app > Click on your own card > Add phone number