# Mobile number not showing for autofill on ios 13

Tags: ios13, autofill

On iOS 13 devices mobile number is not showing for autofill. On iOS 11 & iOS 12 devices system is showing mobile number for autofill.Please guide.

Comment: Could you at least describe what kind of issue are you facing?

Comment: Found correct answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236790/after-updating-to-ios-13-suggestionemail-phone-number-first-name-for-uite

Answer (score 2):

Try use `keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation`. It works, but it looks uncomfortable :(

[Apple Developer Forum Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120703)

Comment: Figured out that this line is also needed: phoneField.autocorrectionType = .yes