.telephoneNumber unable to set suggested mobile on UITextfield
.telephoneNumber unable to set suggested mobile number in keyboard to my textfield (run in device only)
lazy var mobileTextField : UITextField = {
        let s = UITextField()
        s.textColor = UIColor.black
        s.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        s.keyboardType = .phonePad
        s.textContentType = .telephoneNumber
        s.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEndOnExit)
        s.delegate = self
        return s
    }()

  @objc override func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("textFieldDidChange = \(textField.text)")
            guard let currentText = textField.text else {
                return
            }
           textField.text = currentText
        }


Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58858378/833395
